# how to query this.. (order a field and have rows with null values go last)

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I have this table named `sample` and having 3 columns: `id`, `kids` and `hobby`

records:

```
1, John
2, Jacob, Computer Games
3, Joe, Swimming
4, Joan, Basketball
5, Jose
```

As obvious as it is, John and Jose have null values in field `hobby`
what i want to query is for the record to show (when sorted field `hobby` ASC)
should be:

```
4, Joan, Basketball
2, Jacob, Computer Games
3, Joe, Swimming
1, John
5, Jose
```

(i have code where i click a sigle button and the order of query goes ascending then descending and vice versa every click)
and if i want to go descending i want the record to show:

```
3, Joe, Swimming
2, Jacob, Computer Games
4, Joan, Basketball
1, John
5, Jose
```

I want to know the correct `ORDER BY` syntax.
Have i been clear with my question? i hope so. pls help :)

Answer (score 0):

The database will not pay attention to the NULL values in an order by, so you could do this to achieve your desired output.

```
SELECT id, kids, hobby
WHERE hobby IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY hobby
UNION
SELECT id, kids, hobby
WHERE hobby IS NULL
```

Comment: can u show me a correct syntax example?  I tried doing your code but mysql gave me error.  "Incorrect usage of Union and ORDER BY. thanks

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL you can also use :
`ORDER BY hobby IS NULL, hobby` or `ORDER BY hobby IS NULL, hobby DESC`

you can also use a case statement (wich is a standard SQL statement):
`ORDER BY case when hobby is null then 1 else 0 end, hobby` or `ORDER BY case when hobby is null then 1 else 0 end, hobby DESC`

This way you filter first by not null, then the hobby

Comment: what if i want to go asc or desc from time to time where should i insert it?

Comment: Just add DESC after the second hobby : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6fdac/2
Basically you attribute a 1 to every null hobby and a 0 to a not null, you filter asc this (putting the null to the bottom), then the second hobby order ASC or DESC depending on your choices. I updated my answer for that

Comment: I tried it brother, it works with DESC but when I tried to go ASC, still null values go on top of the record :(

Comment: You have to make sure that your fields are actually NULL and not just empty strings, If they are empty strings, you can use `ORDER BY case when hobby = '' then 1 else 0 end, hobby ASC|DESC`